# GDB: Insert a breakpoint on external file using address

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, gdb, breakpoints, break

i'm just learning how to use GDB.
I'm trying to set a breakpoint for an external binary that is called by my program. I do not have the source of the other binary, so I can't compile it with the -g option.
Both my file and the other (a Framework) are written in Objective-C.
I managed to find the address of the line where I want to set my break, but of course GDB so not allow to use that, since I'm working with my file.
How can I tell GDB to set a breakpoint on that binary file, on that address?

Answer (score 1):

To break at a specific address you can use:

```
break *0x12345
```

The "*" tells gdb to interpret the remainder of the "linespec" (see the manual) as an expression.

Often, even without debug info, you can still set breakpoints by name.  This will work as long as there are "linker" symbols of whatever flavor in the library, and as long as you know the linkage name.